# Symfony Form Builder with Choice Field leads to Array to string conversion error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Symfony 6
Doctrine 3

I used the `make:form` and `make:crud` commands to auto-generate everything, so I have no clue why this leads to an error. I understand the error; hence it's self-explanatory. But I don't know where and how to fix it.

**My Controller:**

```
#[Route('/{isbn}/edit', name: 'app_isbn_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function edit(Request $request, Isbn $isbn, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(IsbnType::class, $isbn);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_isbn_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('isbn/edit.html.twig', [
        'isbn' => $isbn,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

**My Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Isbn
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="isbn", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="isbn", columns={"isbn"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Isbn
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $isbn;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="simple_array", length=0, nullable=false, options={"default"="Free"})
     */
    private $state = 'Free';

    public function getIsbn(): ?string
    {
        return $this->isbn;
    }

    public function getState(): array
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setState(array $state): self
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**My Form**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Isbn;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class IsbnType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('state', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Free' => 'Free',
                    'Used' => 'Used',
                    'Dead' => 'Dead'
                ],
                'label' => 'State :',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Isbn::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**edit.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Edit Isbn{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Edit Isbn</h1>

    {{ include('isbn/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Update'}) }}

    <a href="{{ path('app_isbn_index') }}">back to list</a>

    {{ include('isbn/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

**_form.html.twig**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**The Error**

> Warning: Array to string conversion

[image]

Comment: possibly it's because of the value of multiple (=false) inside your form class. t expects an array but it might not send an array, try multiple (=true)

Comment: private $state = 'Free';  vs.   public function getState(): array;


$state is string and you are returning an array? How this should work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is coming from your FormType, in your entity you are mixing string and array typehinting for you `state` attribute.

Check:

```php
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="simple_array", length=0, nullable=false, options={"default"="Free"})
     */
    private $state = 'Free';
```

You are affecting the default value `Free` which is a string to your `state` attribute.
I think you should change your attribute and getter/setter to something like:

```php
    private string $state = 'Free';

    public function getState(): string
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setState(string $state): self
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }
```